# Export BigQuery large table to Google Drive

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to export a large table from BigQuery in csv format: This is the response:

```
Table gdrive://home/bq-results-20200325/bq-results-20200325-101125-tc8d5cqgeift.csv too large to be exported to a single file. Specify a uri including a * to shard export. See 'Exporting data into one or more files' in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data.
```

How can I change the destination uri to gdrive://home/bq-results-20200325/bq-results-*.gz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_into_one_or_more_files) says that you can use the field destinationUris and using a single wildcard operator (*). However, it also mentions that you [cannot EXPORT TABLE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_limitations) data to a local file, to Google Sheets, or to Google Drive. The only supported export location is Cloud Storage (GCS), and for more than 1 GB of data you can use a wildcard.

Nonetheless you still can query the table (e.g. SELECT *) and [save the results in Google Driver](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#saving_query_results_to_google_drive), if this an option for you it can be only performed from the BigQuery UI.